# AttributeError --> 'filter' object has no attribute 'append'

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am receiving an Attribute error where filter object has no attribute 'append'. Below is the code for the particular method build_vocab and I am receiving an error in the line word2id.append(("UNK", (len(word2id),0))).

```
def build_vocab(data, min_freq=2, max_percent=.1):
    word2id = {} # id, counts
    i = 1
    for item in data:
        for word in preprocess(item):
            if word not in word2id:
                word2id[word] = [i, 0]
                i += 1
            word2id[word][1] += 1
    total = len(word2id)
    filtered_ids = int(total * max_percent)
    word2id = sorted(word2id.items(), key=lambda x: x[1][1], reverse=True)[filtered_ids:]
    word2id = filter(lambda x: x[1][1] > min_freq, word2id)
    word2id.append(("UNK", (len(word2id), 0)))
    id2word = [k[0] for k in word2id]
    word2id = {k[0]: (i, k[1][1]) for i, k in enumerate(word2id)}
    return id2word, word2id
```

Thanks,
Mike

Comment: You'll need to make it into a list, `word2id = list(filter(lambda x: x[1][1] > min_freq, word2id))`. `filter` changed in Python 3, in Python 2 the `list` call isn't required.

Comment: Thanks Jim Fasarakis Hilliard and it works !!